# How to display custom attribute in related product in related.phtml

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, attributes, theme, product-relations

I need to display custom attribute in related product.

I have tried get value of custom attribute in related product from related.phtml file.

app/design/frontend/base/default/catalog/product/list/related.phtml file.

But not getting print custom attribute. My custom attribute name is "testattr".

```
 foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>

// Start tried Displaying custom attribute

echo "Testattr::" . $_item->getTestattr();

// End tried Displaying custom attribute



            <li class="item">
                <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(50) ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                    <div class="product-details">
                        <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

Any one can help me? i need to display custom attribute value in related product right side sidebar in default magento.

Answer (score 3):

You should override the getItems() function from that particular block to include the attribute you want to use with addAttributeToSelect(). Block is `catalog/product_list_related`.

> ```
> public function getItems()
> {
>     return $this->_itemCollection;
> }
> ```

Check the _prepareData() function in the same block and there you will see how attributes are selected.

> ```
> protected function _prepareData()
> {
>     $product = Mage::registry('product');
>     /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
> ```

```
    $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
        ->setPositionOrder()
        ->addStoreFilter()
    ;
```

At some point you will find a hacky solution to load every product inside the loop and get the attribute you need from there. *That is not a good idea, dont follow that advice if you want to have a decent performance.*